# Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Express Unmanaged C++

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, unmanaged

Is there a way to create an unmanaged C++ Windows Application project in Visual Studio 2010 Express?  Every time I create a new C++ project and begin designing the user interface, I have noticed it is managed C++.

I am very new to Visual Studio.